# Shankaracharya said that ultimately even law of Karma is not right. Is there a scriptural reference where he says this?

Tags: karma, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

Just watched a lecture from Swami Sarvapriyananda on Mandukya upanishad in which he states that Shankaracharya even cuts down the Law of Karma saying that ultimately that also is not true.

In what scripture did he say this?

Comment: Law of karma is being set by Lord himself and explained in brief by Lord krishna himself in Bhagwat Geeta. If law of karma not right that simply means Lord is not right. Lord is not capable enough to set perfect laws of karma to be applied. May be Lord should have hire Shankaracharya to make laws of karma instead of making by himself. Only then we could get perfect laws for us. But it is our bad luck that we got laws build by Lord instead of a human (Shakracharya). How unlucky we are that we lost judgment of our karma from point of view of sharkracharya. Matlab kuch bhi... -_-

Comment: @Rishabh Please give the definition of law of karma you are talking about and a BG reference that translates to that very meaning

Comment: "In what scripture did he say this?" -- Are u looking to know in which of his works did Adi Shakara say this or are there anything in any scriptures that support his claim?

Comment: Dont misunderstand what Shankaracharya said here....These words have great meaning of Wisdom inside. .... If we interpret this law of Karma statment with our ordinary mind, will end up wrongly and follow wrong path of self realization.

One who knows Parabrahma, for him nothing exists. But for ordinary persons, as long as we are attached to Maya, Karma applies.

Comment: @Rickross....specific scripture/scriptures in which Shankaracharya has said this??

Comment: Do you remember the verse no. of Mundaka Upanishad wher3 Sarvapriyananda said this?

Comment: @Pandya . Watch this discussion from 8th minute. He will eventually come on this topic. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GX4VUVwRzUA

Comment: @yashc As per my understanding with this statement laws means "Prarabdh". And Prarabdh is explained by Krishna in BG. Everyone's Prarabdh gets generated by their karma.

Comment: @yashc You can learn about Prarabdh from this vid [प्रारब्ध क्या हे कैसे बनती हे और उसे कौन बनाता हे ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6nppd7d6QE).

Comment: @Rishabh Thank you for the video. To dig deeper, I referred to BG as it is for further explanation on "Prarabdh". I am unable to find any shlok that directly translates to explanation of the three kinds of karma of which "Prarabdh" is a part. The whole text contains only one reference to word "Prarabdha" and that too is quoting "Padam Puran". So do you have any quote for reference from BG that directly specifies the good begets good and vice versa (not the commentary that signifies so as it is subject to bias of the commentator). Any direction will be appreciated

Comment: @PJai I found Swami Vishwananda already answered with the Mandukya Karia and I think there is no other such an ancient and supreme source of Advaita than Gaudapada Karika :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I see some comments referencing prarabhda karma, I see nothing in your question about this. That is answered in *Brahma Sutras* 3.3.27 and the *Mundaka Upanishad* II.ii.8. To answer your question, the law of karma is ultimately not true. The key word is ultimately. From an ultimate standpoint, there is no karma as there is only the one Absolute Existence. Karma exists within the world of causality (the sensual universe), it does not exist beyond. Gaudapada in his *Karika*, commentary (Chapter 4) on the *Mandukya Upanishad* says (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 53. A substance may be the cause of another substance, and a non-substance, the cause of a another non-substance. But the jivas [atman] cannot possible be anything like a substance or a non-substance.
> 54. Thus external appearances (objects) are not caused by the mind, nor is the mind caused by them. Hence thoughtful people hold on to the principle of absolute non-creation.
> 55. As long as a person clings to the belief of causality, he will find cause producing effect. But when this attachment to causality wears away, cause and effect become non-existent.

and Sankara's commentary on this verse:

> As long as a man cherishes faith in causality and say to himself: 'I am the doer. I have done these righteous or unrighteous deeds and I shall reap their results in a future birth'--in other words, as long as he falsely attributes causality to Atman and clings to this belief--he will see cause producing effect. Such a man will be subject to incessant birth and death as a result of his attachment to the belief in causality. But when his clinging to this belief, which is the result of ignorance, is destroyed by the Knowledge of the non-dual Atman--just as possession by a ghost is destroyed by means of incantations, medicinal herbs, etc.--then causality will cease to operate.
>
> 56. As long as a person clings to the belief in causality, samsara will continue to expand for him. But when this attachment to causality wears away, samsara becomes non-existent.

The law of cause and effect is the law of karma. As verse 59 says, the imaginary sprout is born from the imaginary seed. Brahman alone is real. All else is within the realm of maya and is neither real or unreal. As the Asthvakra Samhita says, A man who says he he free, becomes free, a man who says he is bound, remains bound...

Comment: I think you may have in advertently answered my question on this forum (no one responded to it yet), can you confirm?  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/does-atalashanti-prakarana-of-mandukya-upanishad-contradict-demolish-karma-siddh