# Does Atalashanti prakarana of Mandukya Upanishad contradict/demolish karma siddhanta?

Tags: karma, mandukya-upanishad

The gist of Atalashanti Prakarana of Mandukya upanishad appears to be that cause and effect are constructs of an unrealized mind, and consciousness is unborn/eternal. Several verses in this scripture hammer home this conclusion, such as the following:

> IV-28. Therefore consciousness is not born, nor are things perceived
>   by it born. Those who perceive it as having birth, may as well see
>   footprints in the sky.
>
> IV-46. Thus Consciousness is unborn; thus the souls are regarded to be
>   unborn. Those who realise thus certainly do not fall into misfortune.
>
> IV-54. Thus external objects are not born of Consciousness; nor is
>   Consciousness born of external objects. Thus have the wise settled the
>   birthlessness of cause and effect.
>
> IV-55. As long as there is fascination for cause and effect, so long do
>   cause and effect come into existence. When the fascination for cause
>   and effect ceases, there is no further springing up of cause and effect.

Am I misunderstanding this prakarana of Mandukya Upanishad or does it indeed demolish karma siddhAnta?

Comment: Karma and its fruits exist as long we consider involvement of "I" in both and consider ourselves as doer of karmas and enjoyer of its fruits.  But when we come out of this ignorance that I am the "Karta and Bhokta" and our attachment to causality ends. No karmas and the fruits remains. This is the essence.

Comment: If we look at the next verse i.e. no 56 we can find that "As long as there is faith in causality , the (endless ) chain of birth ad death will be there. When that faith is destroyed by knowledge birth and death become non-existence. " it looks like the verses are saying that karma and its fruits are real i.e (world is real) . But ultimately when we get the knowledge they cease to exist for a person who has achieved Atma-Gnana and he understands that ultimately those were illusions.https://archive.org/details/MandukyaUpanishadKarikaWithShankaraBhashya-SwamiNikhilananda/page/n333

Comment: You are conflating two different concepts.

Comment: Swami Vishwananda - Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Good question @VijaySekhar

Comment: No it does not. Those statements are from paramArthika drushti while karma siddhanta is from vyavahArika drushti. Both are valid.

Comment: As long a jiva has an ego of false identification with matter and his soul is attached to world via Prakriti, his subtle body is bound by good-bad Karmas and their fruits, but upanishads or Gyana Kanda are focussed on realizing the real self, immortal Atman which is untouched by Karmas and is also gist of Geeta. "Geeta 3.22 There is no duty for me to do in all the three worlds, O Parth, nor do I have anything to gain or attain. Yet, I am engaged in prescribed duties." Karma Siddhanta is part of Maya, not for Gyanis who have ascended it, just like regular exams are for children, not for adults.